# Script en python para eliminar ramas de un repositorio de Azure devOps

Tags: python, azure, devops

tengo un script para enlistar y eliminar ramas de un periodo de tiempo determinado de un repositorio de Azure devops pero al momento de confirmar la eliminación de estas ramas me sale "error al eliminar la rama   codigo de respuesta: 405", ya revisé los permisos de mi token y los permisos de eliminar rapas o modificar en mi usuario de devops pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error

```
import requests
import base64
import json
from datetime import datetime

organization = '{}'
project = '{}'
repositoryId = '{}'
personalAccessToken = '{}'

base64AuthInfo = base64.b64encode((":" + personalAccessToken).encode()).decode()

url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?api-version=6.0"

response = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Basic " + base64AuthInfo})

response_json = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8-sig'))

fecha_desde = datetime.strptime('2024-03-13', '%Y-%m-%d')
fecha_hasta = datetime.strptime('2024-03-21', '%Y-%m-%d')

branches_to_delete = []

for branch in response_json['value']:
    branchName = branch['name'].split("/")[-1]
    commitId = branch['objectId']
    urlCommit = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?api-version=6.0"
    responseCommit = requests.get(urlCommit, headers={"Authorization": "Basic " + base64AuthInfo})
    responseCommit_json = json.loads(responseCommit.content.decode('utf-8-sig'))
    commitDate = datetime.strptime(responseCommit_json['committer']['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

    if fecha_desde <= commitDate <= fecha_hasta:
        branches_to_delete.append(branchName)

if branches_to_delete:
    print("Las siguientes ramas serán consideradas para borrar:\n" + "\n".join(branches_to_delete))
    confirm = input(f"¿Estás seguro de que quieres borrar estas {len(branches_to_delete)} ramas? (s/n): ")
    if confirm.lower() == 's':
        for branchName in branches_to_delete:
            urlDelete = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs/heads/{branchName}?api-version=6.0"
            responseDelete = requests.delete(urlDelete, headers={"Authorization": "Basic " + base64AuthInfo})
            if responseDelete.status_code == 204:
                print(f"La rama '{branchName}' ha sido eliminada exitosamente.")
            else:
                print(f"Error al eliminar la rama '{branchName}'. Código de respuesta: {responseDelete.status_code}")
else:
    print("No se encontró ninguna rama antes de la fecha indicada.")


intenté verificando los permisos del repositorio de mi usuario y los permisos de acceso del token pero no fue posible y me sigue saliendo el mismo error.
























tengo un script para enlistar y eliminar ramas de un periodo de tiempo determinado de un repositorio de azure devops pero al momento de confirmar la eliminacion de estas ramas me sale "error al eliminar la rama codigo de respuesta: 405", ya revisé los permisos de mi token y los permisos de eliminar rapas o modificar en mi usuario de devops pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error

import requests import base64 import json from datetime import datetime

organization = '{}' project = '{}' repositoryId = '{}' personalAccessToken = '{}'

base64AuthInfo = base64.b64encode((":" + personalAccessToken).encode()).decode()

url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?api-version=6.0"

response = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Basic " + base64AuthInfo})

response_json = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8-sig'))

fecha_desde = datetime.strptime('2024-03-13', '%Y-%m-%d') fecha_hasta = datetime.strptime('2024-03-21', '%Y-%m-%d')

branches_to_delete = []

for branch in response_json['value']: branchName = branch['name'].split("/")[-1] commitId = branch['objectId'] urlCommit = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?api-version=6.0" responseCommit = requests.get(urlCommit, headers={"Authorization": "Basic " + base64AuthInfo}) responseCommit_json = json.loads(responseCommit.content.decode('utf-8-sig')) commitDate = datetime.strptime(responseCommit_json['committer']['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

if fecha_desde <= commitDate <= fecha_hasta:
    branches_to_delete.append(branchName)
if branches_to_delete: print("Las siguientes ramas serán consideradas para borrar:\n" + "\n".join(branches_to_delete)) confirm = input(f"¿Estás seguro de que quieres borrar estas {len(branches_to_delete)} ramas? (s/n): ") if confirm.lower() == 's': for branchName in branches_to_delete: urlDelete = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs/heads/{branchName}?api-version=6.0" responseDelete = requests.delete(urlDelete, headers={"Authorization": "Basic " + base64AuthInfo}) if responseDelete.status_code == 204: print(f"La rama '{branchName}' ha sido eliminada exitosamente.") else: print(f"Error al eliminar la rama '{branchName}'. Código de respuesta: {responseDelete.status_code}") else: print("No se encontró ninguna rama antes de la fecha indicada.")
```

intenté verificando los permisos del repositorio de mi usuario y los permisos de acceso del token pero no fue posible y me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: La respuesta (HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed) indica generalmente que un API no soporta el verbo o comando utilizado, en este caso, delete. No parece ser un tema de permisos, pues eso generalmente devolvería un error 401. ¿Estás seguro que el API soporta borrados?